# Function that concatenates all the single letter (alphabet) characters

Tags: javascript, function, alphabet

Write a function, that concatenates all the single letter (alphabet) characters
arguments and returns a them as one string. This function should ignore all none single alphabet
arguments.

For example, if the function is called with following arguments:

myFunction(“A”, 32, true, “abc”, “b”, “c” 1, ‘<’, ‘=’, true, ‘/’);

it should return the following string: “Abc”;

Invoke your function with the above sample arguments

Comment: Don't post your homework here. This site is for legitimate questions.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing the different items as different params. You can put them into an array and pass it to the function

```
let arr = ['aa', 'a', 'm', '=', '<',3,5];

function joinSingleAlphabets(arr) {
  const regexp = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z]{0,1}$/)
  return arr.filter(item => regexp.test(item)).join('')
}
const joinedAlphabets = joinSingleAlphabets(arr)
```